# Python cannot find module, pip list does

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, environment

So, [this](https://github.com/tharrry/LEDController) was my first time making a python package. I tried and tested and got it to work. This meaning that `pip install .` didn't complain and that

```
$sudo python3
>>>from LEDController import prettyLight
>>>prettyLight().light('whatsapp',100)
```

provided expected output and actions in my LED matrix.

Also `pip list` includes LEDControllerm but as soon as I start python3 anywhere but in the `LEDController` package directory, the module is not being found.

Running `pip install /path/to/LEDController/` is still successfull, as is `pip3 install /path/to/LEDController/`.
Yet I get

```
$sudo python3
>>> import LEDController
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LEDController'
>>> from LEDController import prettyLight
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LEDController'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could we see the directory layout?

Comment: The layout of the package can be found at the provided link. Other than that there is not really one. I tried sarting python3 in a few different places that are not the package directory.

Comment: problem is your `PYTHONPATH` most likely

Comment: Did you run `pip install` or `sudo pip install`?

Comment: @modesitt can you specify? FlyingTeller, both. Also with pip3

Comment: @modesitt Don't change `PYTHONPATH`, ever. There always is a better solution, which is almost always something along the lines of: fix your imports, fix your packaging, change to the right directory.

Comment: @Harri Make sure you are installing for the right Python interpreter. Don't use the `pip` or `pip3` scripts, ever. Instead always prefer the safer explicit way of calling _pip_'s executable module for a specific Python interpreter: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand ...` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you, that did indeed fix it.

Comment: @sinoroc disagree. it is very common at the end of `/venv/bin/activate` for working projects intended to be a pip package (internal or external)

Comment: @modesitt I believe there well could be cases that call for modifying `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`), but these are very rare (never seen such a case myself). Most importantly, I believe instructing others to modify those as a first call, without giving more context or reasons, is simply counter-productive. This particular case is proof. Again: fixing the imports, fixing the packaging/installing, calling `python -m mymodule` instead of `python mymodule.py`, making sure the current working directory is correct, etc. are much more efficient and productive measures.

Comment: agreed - that is probably better for questions like this

Comment: I broke it again. This time python will not find the module at all. Neither using, `python -m`, nor  `python3 -m`, nor  `python3.7 -m`, nor `pip` or  `pip3`. Installation is always successful, but importing it always gives `No module named x`.

Comment: @Harri Just for confirmation, can you make extra sure you are using the right Python interpreter: `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install SomeProject` then `/path/to/pythonX.Y -c 'import something_from_the_project'`?

Answer (score 1):

As @sinoroc said, installing only using `pip` is not the safest option. Instead using `python3 -m pip install /path/to/module` fixed the issue perfectly.

I'll put his link [here](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) so future viewers can read up on why this is.